# QNetworkaccessmanager object connect function dose not calling

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qnetworkaccessmanager

In my project i want to download files from server. I am trying to download files using **Qnetwrokaccessmanager**. in my code am using a connect function like

```
connect(manger_, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(replyFinshed(QNetworkReply*)))
```

On the time execution of project does not call the function replayFinshed()

```
manger_= new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(manger_, SIGNAL(&QNetworkAccessManager::finished), this, SLOT(replyFinshed(QNetworkReply*)));
connect(manger_, SIGNAL(QNetworkReply::error()), SLOT(errmsg(QNetworkReply *)));
QUrl url(str);
QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl(url);
rsult = manger_->get(request);



void Cricbang::replyFinished(QNetworkReply* reply){
    QMessageBox::information(this, "replay", "finished");
    if (reply->error())
    {
        qDebug() << "ERROR!";
        qDebug() << reply->errorString();
    }
    else
    {
        QFile *file = new QFile("saved/team.json");
        if (file->open(QFile::Append))
        {
            file->write(reply->readAll());
            file->flush();
            file->close();
        }
        delete file;
    }

    reply->deleteLater();
  }
```

Comment: typo: change `connect(manger_, SIGNAL(&QNetworkAccessManager::finished), this, SLOT(replyFinshed(QNetworkReply*)));` to `connect(manger_, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, &Cricbang::replyFinished);`. Do not combine the old connection style (SIGNAL and SLOT) with the new syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
connect(manger_, SIGNAL(&QNetworkAccessManager::finished), this, SLOT(replyFinshed(QNetworkReply*)));
```

to

```
connect(manger_, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyFinshed(QNetworkReply*)));
```

or use the new syntax introduced in Qt5 like [eyllanesc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6622587/eyllanesc) suggested

```
connect(manger_, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, &Cricbang::replyFinshed);
```

See more at https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax